# Typescript defining type for object key's value same as object itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I define a common type for cart item and its addons. Both cart item and addons will have same keys :

```
type iCart = {
  productId: string
  name: string
  description: string
  unitPrice: number
  netTotal: number
  quantity: number
  taxTotals?: { [key: string]: string }[]
  addons:[
   addonId: string
   name: string
   description: string
   unitPrice: number
   netTotal: number
   quantity: number
   taxTotals?: { [key: string]: string }[]
  ]
}
```

However I'd like to define a type and use it. Tried by intersection types but I'm not sure if it's correct  :

```
export type iCartItem = {
  productId: string
  addonId:string
  name: string
  description: string
  unitPrice: number
  netTotal: number
  quantity: number
  taxTotals?: { [key: string]: string }[]
  period: iPeriod
}
type iCart = Omit<iCartItem, 'addonId'> & { addons?: Omit<iCartItem, 'productId'>[] }
```

It doesn't look right to me since hovering on type on my IDE doesn't show keys. Is there a more robust way to do it?

Comment: A better approach is to identify the things that a cart item and an addon have in common and to decide if they are related concepts or is it just a coincidence. If you decide that they are related, what is their relationship? Is one of them a specialization of the other? Or maybe both are specializations of a common abstract concept. Is an addon a standalone concept? Can it be a cart item (in a different cart)? Or it always needs to be attached to a "main" item? Use the answers to these questions and many others to design the data types. Don't just throw everything in a common type.

Comment: I think defining types for product and addon separately will be the best approach. I'll look into a way to merge their common keys instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
type iCart = {
  productId: string
  name: string
  description: string
  unitPrice: number
  netTotal: number
  quantity: number
  taxTotals?: { [key: string]: string }[]
  addons:[
   addonId: string
   name: string
   description: string
   unitPrice: number
   netTotal: number
   quantity: number
   taxTotals?: { [key: string]: string }[]
  ]
}
```

This code defines your custom type `iCart`, now just use this as any other default types, for eg:

```
const exampleICartObject: iCart = {
type iCart = {
  // Fill in the required properties
}
```

To get field suggestions:

```
type iCart = {
   /**
   * Enter description for productId field
   */
  productId: string
   /**
   * Enter description for name field
   */
  name: string
}
```

*Read More: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-types-in-typescript*